# Variance of Poisson and Exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

I have encountered a problem with the variance of Poisson and exponential distribution.
Suppose there is an accident that follows a Poisson distribution with an occurrence rate of $\lambda$ per hour. The fuel needed for each accident follows an exponential distribution with mean $\mu$. I want to know the distribution of the fuel consumption per hour. The mean is quite straightforward, it should be just $\lambda * \mu$, but what about the variance(standard deviation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's formalize the problem. We have $N$~Pois$(\lambda)$, $X_i \overset{i.i.d}{\sim}  Exp(1/\mu)$ and we are interested in
$$S= \begin{cases}
    \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i, & \text{if } N > 0 \\
    0, & \text{if } N = 0
\end{cases}$$

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var} \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E}
 $

This is a case of [compound Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), and we can derive formulas for its variance and expectation.

Using law of total variance: $$\Var (S) = \E(\Var(S|N)) + \Var(\E(S|N)) \label{eq:pythagoras}.$$
Then we need derive $\Var(S|N)$ and $\E(S|N)$ :
$$\E(S|N=n) = \E(\sum_{i=1}^N X_i|N=n) = \E(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i|N=n) = n \E(X_i|N=n) = n\E(X_i),$$
therefore $\E(S|N) = N \E (X_i) $. Similarly we get that $\Var(S|N) = N \Var(X_i) $.

Now let's substitute it to our formula for $\Var(S)$: $$\Var(S) = \E(N\Var(X_i)) + \Var(E(X_i) N).$$

Here $\Var(X_i)$ and $E(X_i)$ are just constants, therefore:
$$\Var(S)= \E(N) \Var(X_i) + (\E (X_i) )^2 \Var(N).$$

In our problem $\E(X_i)=\mu, \Var(X_i)=\mu^2, \E(N)=\Var(N)=\lambda$.

Therefore $\Var(S) = 2 \mu^2 \lambda$.

Comment: Just as an aside, this type of calculation comes up frequently in actuarial math where the number of insurance claims are modeled by Poisson and the loss per claim by exponential or some other common distribution.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_1,E_2,...\sim \exp(\frac{1}{\mu})$ be iid.

Fix $t\geq 0$, and let $A(t)\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ denote the number of accidents that took plane on $[0,t]$. Assume $t$ is in hours and $A(t),E_1,E_2,...$ are independent.

You're trying to find the distribution of the random variable $$C(t)=E_1+\dots +E_{A(t)}$$

$C(t)$ is the amount of fuel consumed on $[0,t]$.

If we take $\mathcal{E}(t)\sim \text{Poisson}(t/\mu)$ then for $\tau \geq 0$ we have $C(t)\leq \tau$ if and only if $\mathcal{E}(\tau)\geq A(t)$ whose probability doesn't have a nice closed form, so from here I decided to try another approach.

By conditioning on $A(t)$ and using double expectation, we see that the moment generating function of $C(t)$ is $$\begin{eqnarray*}M_{C(t)}(s) &=& \mathbb{E}\Big(e^{C(t)s}\Big) &=& \mathbb{E}\left((1-\mu s)^{-A(t)}\right) &=& e^{-\lambda t}e^{\frac{\lambda t}{1-\mu s}}\end{eqnarray*}$$

But this means $$e^{-\lambda t}e^{\frac{\lambda t}{1-\mu s}}=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{C(t)}(\tau)e^{s\tau}\mathrm{d}\tau$$

We can now say $f_{C(t)}(\tau)$ is $e^{-\lambda t}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\Big(e^{\frac{\lambda t}{1+\mu s}}\Big)(\tau)$ where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform. (Here $\mathcal{L}$ maps a function of $\tau$ to a function of $s$).

This inverse Laplace transform doesn't seem to exist since $e^{\frac{\lambda t}{1+\mu s}}$ doesn't approach $0$ as $s$ gets large.

Does this mean the pdf of $C(t)$ isn't of exponential order?

Let's try another method.

We know that $C(t)|A(t)\sim \text{Gamma}(A(t),\frac{1}{\mu})$ (in shape$-$rate parameterization) and  $A(t)\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ so by using total law $f_{C(t)}(\tau)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_{C(t)|A(t)=k}(\tau|k)\mathbb{P}(A(t)=k)$ we have $$f_{C(t)}(\tau)=\frac{1}{\tau}\exp\Big(-\frac{\tau}{\mu}-\lambda t\Big) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(k-1)!}\Big(\frac{\lambda t }{\mu}\tau\Big)^k+f_{C(t)|A(t)=0}(\tau|0)e^{-\lambda t}$$ But $f_{C(t)|A(t)=0}(\tau|0)=\delta(\tau)$ and, according to Wolfram alpha, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!(k-1)!}\Big(\frac{\lambda t }{\mu}\tau\Big)^k=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{\mu}\tau}\cdot \mathcal{I}_1\Big(2\sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{\mu}\tau}\Big)$ where $\mathcal{I}_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. Finally, $$f_{C(t)}(\tau)=\frac{1}{\tau}\exp\Big(-\frac{\tau}{\mu}-\lambda t\Big)\sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{\mu}\tau}\cdot \mathcal{I}_1\Bigg(2\sqrt{\frac{\lambda t}{\mu}\tau}\Bigg)+e^{-\lambda t}\delta(\tau)$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you set up the equality between e^C(t)s and (1-mu*s)^(-A(t))?

Comment: Do you know $\mathbb{E}(C(t))=\mathbb{E}\Big(\mathbb{E}(C(t)|A(t))\Big)$ ?

Comment: Yes, I do have knowledge about this equation.